# Creating a line chart from data with multiple date rows per date?

Tags: excel, charts, linechart, libreoffice-calc

I'm struggling to create a line chart with three lines in Excel or Libreoffice Calc. I would like to have the X axis be the date and the y axis for the counts.

I have my data (the result of a SQL query) in three columns, it looks like this (there are more rows):

```
date        version count
10.07.19    2.10    1734
10.07.19    3.2       52
10.07.19    3.11    1224
11.07.19    2.10    1897
11.07.19    3.2      108
11.07.19    3.11    1238
```

I would like to create a line diagram with three lines, one for each possible value of the "version" column. From my limited knowledge of spreadsheet programs i think i need all "count" values on a single row to create a diagram. 
So I have two questions:

- Can I create a diagram without having all counts belonging to one date on a single line?
- If not, how do I get those counts on a single line? Something with filtering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Pivot table, with the date as the rows, and the version as the columns, and the Data fields the count.

```
count           version         
date            2.1     3.11    3.2     Total Result
10.07.19        1734    1224    52      3010
11.07.19        1897    1238    108     3243
Total Result    3631    2462    160     6253
```

Then you can generate the chart from this table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: Select the data (all three columns).  From the menu  Insert , choose  "Pivot Table".  
Choose as data source  "Current Selection". --> Then a popup window appears where you can choose the available fields (on the right), and move them to: - choose   "date"    for the "Row Fields", - choose   "version" for the "Column Fields", - choose   "count"   for the "Data Fields" .  --  You will find the pivot table in a new sheet. Note: if you right-click on the pivot table, you can "Refresh" the table.